# Convert object to array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I need to obtain an array like this

```
[
  "CD_DIRECAO",
  "DT_INI_DIRECAO",
  "CD_DEPT",
  "DT_INI_DEPT"
]
```

from this array of objects

```
[
    {
      "CD_DIRECAO": "400"
    },
    {
      "DT_INI_DIRECAO": "1900-01-01"
    },
    {
      "CD_DEPT": "370"
    },
    {
      "DT_INI_DEPT": "1900-01-01"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map()` and `Object.keys` methods with spread syntax `...`.

```js
const data = [{"CD_DIRECAO":"400"},{"DT_INI_DIRECAO":"1900-01-01"},{"CD_DEPT":"370"},{"DT_INI_DEPT":"1900-01-01"}]

const result = [].concat(...data.map(Object.keys))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Cleanest answer.

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can use Object#assign and spread to merge the objects, and then get the keys using Object#keys:

```js
const arr = [{"CD_DIRECAO":"400"},{"DT_INI_DIRECAO":"1900-01-01"},{"CD_DEPT":"370"},{"DT_INI_DEPT":"1900-01-01"}];

const obj = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could use [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) and [**keys**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys):

```
let result = _.flatMap(data, _.keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might look a bit hacky but it gives the right output

```
    const data = [
        {
          "CD_DIRECAO": "400"
        },
        {
          "DT_INI_DIRECAO": "1900-01-01"
        },
        {
          "CD_DEPT": "370"
        },
        {
          "DT_INI_DEPT": "1900-01-01"
        }
    ];

const newData = data.map(item => _.keys(item)).map(item => item[0]);
console.log(newData);
```

This will give the output as `[ 'CD_DIRECAO', 'DT_INI_DIRECAO', 'CD_DEPT', 'DT_INI_DEPT' ]`